# Mint 19: For "power is critically low" How to enable Hibernate option?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, hibernate

I have hibernate/suspend option available during closing the lid. Its not the hardware problem as this option is available on Windows and it works. But there's no suspend option when the power is critically low.
**I wanted to ask is there any way i can add that option?**

*[ Linux Mint 19.1 Cinnamon
4.15.0-45-generic ]*

Answer (score 0):

1. Run command in Terminal
   **gksudo gedit /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/com.ubuntu.desktop.pkla**
2. A file opens up, find the following parts

   [Disable hibernate by default in upower]
   [Disable hibernate by default in logind]

Change both the values in **ResultActive** section from **no to yes**